# What is the connection between Hashem's battle with the dragon and creation in Tehilim Chapter 74?

Tags: midrash, animals, tehilim-psalms, creation

Tehilim 74:13-17 recounts a series of victories of Hashem. The first couplet documents victories in battle against both the *tanin* and the *Leviathan*:

> אַתָּ֤ה פוֹרַ֣רְתָּ בְעׇזְּךָ֣ יָ֑ם שִׁבַּ֖רְתָּ רָאשֵׁ֥י תַ֝נִּינִ֗ים עַל־הַמָּֽיִם׃
>
> 13 You divided the sea by your might; you broke the heads of the dragons in the waters. (NSRV)

> אַתָּ֣ה רִ֭צַּצְתָּ רָאשֵׁ֣י לִוְיָתָ֑ן תִּתְּנֶ֥נּוּ מַ֝אֲכָ֗ל לְעָ֣ם לְצִיִּֽים׃
>
> 14 You crushed the heads of Leviathan; you gave him as food for the creatures of the wilderness.

Then turns to acts of creating day/night, waters, stars, and seasons:

> אַתָּ֣ה בָ֭קַעְתָּ מַעְיָ֣ן וָנָ֑חַל אַתָּ֥ה ה֝וֹבַ֗שְׁתָּ נַהֲר֥וֹת אֵיתָֽן׃
>
> 15 You cut openings for springs and torrents; you dried up ever-flowing streams.

> לְךָ֣ י֭וֹם אַף־לְךָ֥ לָ֑יְלָה אַתָּ֥ה הֲ֝כִינ֗וֹתָ מָא֥וֹר וָשָֽׁמֶשׁ׃
>
> 16 Yours is the day, yours also the night; you established the luminaries and the sun.

> אַתָּ֣ה הִ֭צַּבְתָּ כׇּל־גְּבוּל֣וֹת אָ֑רֶץ קַ֥יִץ וָ֝חֹ֗רֶף אַתָּ֥ה יְצַרְתָּֽם׃
>
> 17 You have fixed all the bounds of the earth; you made summer and winter.

What is the connection between the victories against these monsters and the creation account here? Why does one follow the other?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the first part, namely the sea serpent and the levyoson, both are used as they are descriptions of Pharoah who saw himself as a deity.

[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.74.13?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Psalms.74.13.1&lang2=bi) tells us on pasuk 13:

> ושברת ראשי אויבינו במים דימה מצרים לתנינים
>
> And breaking the heads of our enemies in the water, Egypt was likened to serpents

Indeed, refer to [Yechezkel 29:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.29.3?lang=bi):

> הִנְנִ֤י עָלֶ֙יךָ֙ פַּרְעֹ֣ה מֶלֶךְ־מִצְרַ֔יִם הַתַּנִּים֙ הַגָּד֔וֹל הָרֹבֵ֖ץ בְּת֣וֹךְ יְאֹרָ֑יו אֲשֶׁ֥ר אָמַ֛ר לִ֥י יְאֹרִ֖י וַאֲנִ֥י עֲשִׂיתִֽנִי
>
> I am going to deal with you, O Pharaoh king of Egypt, mighty monster, sprawling in your channels, who said, my Nile is my own; I made it for myself.

In a similar vein, [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.74.13?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Psalms.74.14.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) continues on the next pasuk (14):

> ראשי לויתן. הוא פרעה כי לויתן פירושו התנין הגדול כמו על לויתן נחש בריח: ואמר ראשי. על שלישיו ועל גבוריו
>
> The head of the Levyoson - this is Pharoah because Levyoson mean the big serpent like the fleeing snake/serpent. And the heads said - this is a reference to his officers and generals (of his army).

It therefore follows that the proceeding verses go on to talk about G-d's creation in order to demonstrate how Hashem it is so vastly superior to Pharoah, who was a mere, self-proclaimed deity.

The commentaries on the subsequent pesukim really underline this vast difference by showcasing just how wondrous G-d's creation is. For example, in pasuk 17 where it says:

> אַתָּ֣ה הִ֭צַּבְתָּ כׇּל־גְּבוּל֣וֹת אָ֑רֶץ
>
> You fixed all the boundaries of the earth

Note the [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.74.17?lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.74.17.1&lang2=bi) who observes that Hashem created seven distinctly different climate zones, each precisely placed in the right geographical location (Metzudos Dovid) and how each landscape contributes a unique purpose [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.74.17?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Psalms.74.17.1&lang2=bi).